# Find the MLE estimator for $\theta$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let $Y_1 ,Y_2 ,\ldots,Y_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with pdf

$f(y) =  e^{-(y -\theta) }$ for $y \geq 0 $ and $0$ else

a) Find the Method of Moments estimator for $\theta$

b) Find the MLE estimator for $\theta$

I'm pretty sure I found out how to do a) but b) I'm having trouble with. Everytime I take the logarithm and then take the derivative, $\theta$ disappears, any help?

Comment: What you wrote is not a pdf. Do you mean $y\ge\theta$ in the definition instead?

Comment: Note that $f(y)=e^{-(y-\theta)}$ for $y\geq \theta$. So may be the smallest $Y_i$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019525/mle-of-delta-for-the-distribution-fx-e-delta-x-for-x-geq-delta?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MLE estimator is by definition $\hat\theta$ which maximizes
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n{\mathrm e}^{-(Y_k-\theta)},\quad\theta\in\left(-\infty,\min(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)\right],
$$
or equivalently (by taking the logarithm),
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(\theta-Y_k),\quad\theta\in\left(-\infty,\min(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)\right].
$$
This is an increasing function of $\theta$, so...

Comment: Ha, it is the smallest $Y_n$.

Comment: so the MLE is the $max(Y_1 ,...,Y_n)$ ?

Comment: or is it the $min(Y_1, ... , Y_1)$ ? Being the max would make more sense to me since its an increasing but everyone here seems to say its the min?

Comment: @AlexChavez, $\theta$ is in the interval $(-\infty,\min(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)]$ so it cannot be the maximum which is outside the interval.

Comment: oh okay makes sense thank you!